# Error fetch image from storage with message 'Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableContentType'

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofireimage, alamofire-request

I attemp to fetch image from Firebase storage, but have error message:

> Alamofire.AFError.responseValidationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableContentType(acceptableContentTypes: ["image/x-xbitmap", "image/jpeg", "application/octet-stream", "image/gif", "image/ico", "image/tiff", "image/x-icon", "image/bmp", "image/x-bmp", "image/x-win-bitmap", "image/png", "image/x-ms-bmp"], responseContentType: "application/json")

My url looks like this: **https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/####/o/executors/o4uAQa158nXTvJ5omuxqcRb0e793/products/7DDCEEAC-ED54-4910-B93D-5E40BF411B80**

I can download this image via browser.

My image has MIME-type 'image/jpeg':[image]

I found the same situation:

1. [Response Content-Type was missing and acceptable content types](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/issues/301)
2. [Make sure you set alamofire acceptable content types](https://github.com/sendbird/SendBird-iOS/issues/21)
3. [Image Response Serializers](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage#usage)

These hints didn't help me to fix my bug.

Version of pod:

- Alamofire: 5.0.2
- AlamofireImage 4.0.2

Initially I used *AlamofireImage*: `productImageView.af.setImage(withURL: url)`, but it didn't work. Then I began using *Alamofire*. And into request I pass MIME-type **image/jpeg** like **Content-Type**: [image]

And I decided to use this approach to fix bug, but has the same error and I don't understand why([from docs](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/pull/33/files/3e5b99c88049e1f067f00e85890634c3df89ebf5)):
[image]

If you can see in error-message I have:

> responseContentType: "application/json"

So does it have any side effect to fetch image? What I do wrong at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link should be

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/projectname/o/image.png?alt=media&token=auth_token

replace projectname , image name and token to yours

Answer (score -1):

First, your request headers have nothing do with whether the response is valid, so adding `image/jpeg` there won't help. Second, your response is return an `application/json` content type, so adding `image/jpeg` to the acceptable content types won't help (and `image/jpeg` is already acceptable). (As an aside, you need to `import AlamofireImage` to get `addAcceptableImageContentTypes` to work.)

In the end, you should ensure you're getting the response you expect, as an `application/json` content type implies you're getting a JSON body, not an image fro your request. When I request the URL you posted, I get this JSON response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid HTTP method/URL pair."
  }
}
```

So most likely you need to double check how you're supposed to be making the request.

Comment: Thanks for answer) I added **import AlamofireImage** to have access, but it didn't work. And I give you wrong url - you can see  **####** in url, because I think it's private information. Sorry for that.

Comment: I test right url in browser's address bar and, you are right, I have 400 code of error. I don't know why, actually.